# Ordering Axis Labels using reorder_within

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, facet-wrap

I am trying to order my axis labels using the function "reorder within" described in this link here: https://juliasilge.com/blog/reorder-within/ with one slight change - setting the values for 2 individuals to be the same.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
library(tidytext)
library(babynames)
library(tidyverse)

top_names <- babynames %>%
  filter(year >= 1950,
         year < 1990) %>%
  mutate(decade = (year %/% 10) * 10) %>%
  group_by(decade) %>%
  count(name, wt = n, sort = TRUE) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(n = ifelse(decade == "1950" & name == "Michael", 846042, n)) #Added to create 2 rows with a tie. 


top_names %>%
  group_by(decade) %>%
  top_n(15) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(decade = as.factor(decade),
         name = reorder_within(name, n, decade)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, n, fill = decade)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~decade, scales = "free_y") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_reordered() +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  labs(y = "Number of babies per decade",
       x = NULL,
       title = "What were the most common baby names in each decade?",
       subtitle = "Via US Social Security Administration")
```

I'm able to run the code perfectly, but my problem is that I want to reverse the order of names on the y axis (least common on top and most common on bottom). I can do this with changing the line with the reorder_within to:

```
  mutate(decade = as.factor(decade),
         name = reorder_within(name, -n, decade))
```

However this flips the order of the names "Michael and Joseph", which I don't want to have happen.

How do I specify that when there is a tie, I want the names to still be in alphabetical order?

Comment: Or, better yet, save your filtered `top_names` right before you plot it and share `dput(filtered_top_names)` with us. Then we can help you without installing the `babynames` package.

Answer (score 4):

TBMK `reorder_within` does not offer different options to deal with ties. However, one option would be to rearrange your dataset in your desired order after applying `reorder_within` and to (re)set the factor levels using `forcats::fct_inorder`:

```r
library(tidytext)
library(babynames)
library(tidyverse)

top_names %>%
  group_by(decade) %>%
  top_n(15) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(decade = as.factor(decade),
         name = reorder_within(name, -n, decade)) %>%
  arrange(decade, desc(n), desc(name)) %>% 
  mutate(name = fct_inorder(name)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(name, n, fill = decade)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(aes(label = n), hjust = 1) +
  facet_wrap(~decade, scales = "free_y") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_reordered() +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  labs(y = "Number of babies per decade",
       x = NULL,
       title = "What were the most common baby names in each decade?",
       subtitle = "Via US Social Security Administration")
#> Selecting by n
```

[image]